# Openmodelica Compilation

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, openmodelica

I'm having problems compiling OpenAI on Windows, I think I've installed the dependencies and configured the environment variables, but I keep getting errors at compile time:
fatal error: 'algorithm'file not found

I want to know what the problem is. I was able to find the C++ standard library and also preprocessed a little bit of code using 'algorithm' and found that the compiler could find this header file